# Accessing array of hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

1. I have problem with accessing a hash in each element of array after creating it but it gave the last element. What should I do to access all the elements of my array?
2. When I want push a hash to an array I use `{}` instead of `()` because if I don't it gave me error. How does it see when I use {}?

```perl
    @stem = ();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
        push @stem, { u1 => 1, u2 => 2 , u3 => 3 };
    }

    @ants = ();
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@stem); ++$i) {
        @allowed = ();
        %hash = ();
        for ($j = 0; $j < scalar(@stem); ++$j) {
            push @allowed, { stem => ++$count, hinfo => ++$count };
        }
        %hash = (allowed => \@allowed, solution => ++$count);
        push (@ants, \%hash);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@ants); ++$i) {

        %test = %{$ants[$i]};
        print "=>", $test{solution}, "\n";
        @temp = @{$test{allowed}};

        for ($j = 0; $j < scalar(@temp); ++$j) {
            print $j, ":", $temp[$j]->{stem}, " ", $temp[$j]->{hinfo}, "\n";
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
=>21
0:16 16
1:18 18
2:20 20
=>21
0:16 16
1:18 18
2:20 20
```

Comment: Please can you show an MCVE ([MCVE]) of your code.  In particular, we need something equivalent to what you have as the `@stems` array.  It needn't contain more than a couple of entries, and there might not be any need to read data (hand-craft the data structure).

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it isn't clear that we know from the code what `$length`, `@seq1`, `@seq2`, `@matrix` are.  An MCVE allows us to run your code.  We shouldn't have to spend time working out what it is that you've got.

Comment: Why not write the extra information as: `my @seq1 = ('a','a','b');
my @seq2 = ('b','a','b');
my @matrix = ( 
    [0,1,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,0,1],
    );  
my $length = 2;`?  Do you run with `use strict; use warnings;`?  I don't run Perl code without them; I've only been using it 20-plus years and I don't know it well enough to risk not using them.  When I do run your code, I get told that the `if($matrix[$i+$w][$j+$w] eq "."){++$count;}` line is accessing the array out of bounds.  Also, if the array contains 0 and 1 values, when will an element ever equal `"."`?

Comment: sorry... I rewrite the code you can run it ... I don't use  `use strict; use warnings` is it necessary to use them ??? ... for the matrix it contain space and dots but i didn't pay attention sorry

Comment: Get in the habit of using them both — always.  It probably doesn't matter here at the moment, but better safe than sorry.  I wouldn't post Perl code on SO without them — too much risk of making an fool of myself without.

Comment: Add `use Data::Dumper;` to the top of your script.  Add `print Dumper(\@stems);` or perhaps `print "\n", Data::Dumper->Dump([\@stems], [qw(\@stems)]), "\n";` to show what's in the `@stems` array, and similarly for the `@ants` array.  With a little practice, that will tell you a lot about your data structure contents.  I'm not sure I understand what you want, but I can see what you get from the version of the code I first copied.  It looks like I need to start over; your need code seems to be quite a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) When I want push a hash to an array I use `{}` instead of `()` because if I don't it gave me error. How does it see when I use `{}`?

I can answer this Question 2.

When you use `()` perl sees as list of elements. When you use `{}` perl sees it as reference to a hash.

So When you do this: `push @Arr, (x=>2, y=>5);` four elements will be pushed to `@Arr`: `x`, `2`, `y`, `5`. Which is not your intention.

But When you do this: `push @Arr , {x => 2, y => 5};` a single reference to an anonymous hash containing `x` and `y` as the keys, and `2` and `5` as the respective values will be pushed to `@Arr`.